# Include inserted data like ObjectId to response in node/express

Tags: mongodb, express, postman

I am trying to insert an ObjectId in postman, in Headers for Content-Type, I use multipart/form-data

[image]

and keep getting an error

```
{
    "errors": {
        "singer": {
            "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"ObjectId(\"5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801\")\" at path \"singer\"",
            "name": "CastError",
            "stringValue": "\"ObjectId(\"5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801\")\"",
            "kind": "ObjectID",
            "value": "ObjectId(\"5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801\")",
            "path": "singer",
            "reason": {
                "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"ObjectId(\"5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801\")\" at path \"singer\"",
                "name": "CastError",
                "stringValue": "\"ObjectId(\"5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801\")\"",
                "kind": "ObjectId",
                "value": "ObjectId(\"5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801\")",
                "path": "singer"
            }
        }
    },
    "_message": "Song validation failed",
    "message": "Song validation failed: singer: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"ObjectId(\"5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801\")\" at path \"singer\"",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Here's my code for routes, and pass ObjectId in singer field as req.body

```
router.post('/addSoloSong', mp3.single('mp3File'), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file)
  console.log(req.body.singer);

  const newSong = new Song({
    title: req.body.title,
    singer: req.body.singer,
    releaseDate: Date.parse(req.body.releaseDate),
    mp3File: req.file.path,
    createdAt: new Date()
  })
  try {
    let songAdded = await newSong.save()
    res.status(201).json(songAdded)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    res.status(400).json(err)
  }
})
```

and created the singer field as an ObjectId

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const songSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  singer: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Singer",
    required: true
  },
  featureSinger: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Singer"
  },
  groupBand: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'GroupBand'
  },
  releaseDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  mp3File: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: "/public/mp3"
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: null
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: null
  },
  deletedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: null
  },
  assignedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: null
  }
});

const Song = mongoose.model("Song", songSchema);

module.exports = Song;
```

I wanted to pass the ObjectId as I inserted it in form data, what am I missing? 
And I also wanna ask on mp3File in postman, it says, the file isn't in your working directory? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending singer value as a string.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.post('/addSoloSong', mp3.single('mp3File'), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file)
  console.log(req.body.singer);

  const newSong = new Song({
    title: req.body.title,
    singer: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.singer),
    releaseDate: Date.parse(req.body.releaseDate),
    mp3File: req.file.path,
    createdAt: new Date()
  })
  try {
    let songAdded = await newSong.save()
    res.status(201).json(songAdded)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    res.status(400).json(err)
  }
})
```

This will work.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to apply mongoose. Thanks. I'll try it first

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6543) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code`
I have this error after trying that

Comment: Igot it! I just remove the word **ObjectId** in postman, requesting for singer field.